# Multiquery from *.sql file without access to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I destroyed database (wrong MyBB upgrade), but i have got backup in *.sql file. I dont have access to MySQL (im not on white-list MySQL - error from the admin server), but i can send data from the server, using PHP... How do that if i have - for example this - (~50000 lines)?:

```
INSERT INTO mybb_posts (`pid`..some string..'0');
INSERT INTO mybb_posts (`pid`..some string..'0');
```

Comment: The answer below is good, but also note that assuming you have permissions to create new PHP files on the server, that should be all you need to install your own copy of phpMyAdmin. Depending on the server configuration you may even be able to create the phpMyAdmin folder as a symlink to a folder above the web root, in case having the phpMyAdmin folder within your web root would mess with your version control or be inconvenient for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* credentials */);
foreach (explode(';', file_get_contents('file.sql')) as $query) {
    $pdo->query($query);
}
```

If you run out of time, use `set_time_limit(0)`.  If that doesn't work, consider splitting up the file and running fewer queries at a time.  Same if you're running out of memory.